# HBase not starting after adding the jar file with Mapper/Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to write a Mapper/Reducer for hbase and I added the jar. However after adding the jar file in lib directory, I cannot start hbase. I want to debug what is going wrong? How can I change the log level? Will it help?
Following is the exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.addMaster(LocalHBaseCluster.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.(LocalHBaseCluster.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2290)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolProxy(Ljava/lang/Class;JLjava/net/InetSocketAddress;Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljavax/net/SocketFactory;ILorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/RetryPolicy;Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/ipc/ProtocolProxy;
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:665)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2625)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2607)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.getRootDir(FSUtils.java:1004)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.(HRegionServer.java:562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.(HMaster.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.(HMasterCommandLine.java:307)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:139)
        ... 7 more

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the error was due to mismatch of hadoop libraries in the lib directory of HBase(which was hadoop-*-2.5.1) against my actual Hadoop installation(hadoop-*-2.6.0). My jar was looking for classes which it was not finding in the older version of the hadoop libraries due to which it was failing. [this answer](http://answers.mapr.com/answers/161631/view.html) made me realize the issue. After I copied all the hadoop-*-2.6.0 jars in the lib directory, HBase started as expected. The same is also mentioned in [HBase-Hadoop compatibility documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop).